# Update a controller variable after an ajax request

Tags: ajax, angularjs

i'm new on AngularJS and i spent hours trying ti figure out what wrong whith my code...

```
    var articles = angular.module('Articles', []).config(function($interpolateProvider){
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{§').endSymbol('§}');
    });

    articles.controller('CommentsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {        
     this.comments = [];

     this.showComments = function (index) {                     
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '{{ path ('backend_article_commentaires')}}',
            data: {articleID:index}
          })
          .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              comments = data;
          })
          .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
             console.log(data)
          });
          }
        }]);
```

the problem is that the ***comments*** variable dont change...

please how can i solve this ?

Update:

```
<div class="md-modal md-effect-13" id="modal-comments"
    ng-controller="CommentsCtrl as ctrl">
    <div class="md-content">
        <h3>
            <i class="fa fa-comments"></i> Tous les commentaires
        </h3>
        <div>
            <div id="list-comment">
                <h4>Cet article n'a aucun commentaires...</h4>
                <li ng-repeat="comment in ctrl.comments" class="media">
                  <a>{{ comment.title }}</a>
                </li>
            </div>
            <div class="button-row">
                <button class="btn btn-danger md-close md-yes">Fermer</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to do this.comments=data

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work :/

Comment: wy do you say it doesn't? are you exploring the scope with devtools or is it because your data dosn't show in a page?

Comment: i use the an ng-repeat to display my comments list, i just added the code below

Comment: snd you are certain that you are getting data back

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is one of scopes (and not angular scopes) the this in your success function would not be the same as your this in your controller. If you assign "this" to a variable in the controller and then reference that you should be good to go.

```
articles.controller('CommentsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {        
    this.comments = [];

    var rootThis = this;

    this.showComments = function (index) {                     
    $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '{{ path ('backend_article_commentaires')}}',
            data: {articleID:index}
        })
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            rootThis.comments = data;
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data)
        });
    }
}]);
```

As you can see I created a rootThis variable to hold the "this" that way I can use it in the success function

Comment: i tried this but it doesn't seems to work, i can't event do that alert(rootThis.comments)

Comment: Can you please create a jsFiddle

Comment: Your url seems very off, why is it in brackets?